# RabbitMQ - Join_Cluster - no function clause matching

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I have 2 RabbitMQ servers and trying to cluster as per this link https://haptik.ai/tech/rabbitmq-cluster-failover/. Done all the required settings in server1 and in the server2 when i execute the below statement. I am getting the error

> rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@server1.domain.com

Please find below the detailed error message

```
Clustering node rabbit@INCHNACCWAS01 with rabbit@server1.domain.com
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in RabbitMQCtl.format_error/3

    The following arguments were given to RabbitMQCtl.format_error/3:

        # 1
        {:badmatch, {:error, {:node_name, :short}}}

        # 2
        %{disc: false, longnames: false, node: :rabbit@INCHNACCWAS01, ram: false, timeout: :infinity}

        # 3
        RabbitMQ.CLI.Ctl.Commands.JoinClusterCommand

    (rabbitmqctl) lib/rabbitmqctl.ex:367: RabbitMQCtl.format_error/3
    (rabbitmqctl) lib/rabbitmqctl.ex:124: anonymous fn/5 in RabbitMQCtl.exec_command/2
    (rabbitmqctl) lib/rabbitmqctl.ex:45: RabbitMQCtl.main/1
    (elixir) lib/kernel/cli.ex:105: anonymous fn/3 in Kernel.CLI.exec_fun/2
```

Comment: Erlang cookie file the same among all nodes?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in that version of RabbitMQ. Please upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rabbitmqctl status` for more information.

```
[root@node1 ~]# rabbitmqctl status
Status of node rabbit@node1 ...
```

Which means you current node name is `node1`, and you should use
`rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@node1` command. Sometimes the RABBITMQ nodename is NOT the same as HOSTNAME.

According to this method, you can doublecheck EXACT node name of both this and target instance and then create correct adding-cluster command.

Comment: this problem is hard to spot, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

When I used

```
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@ip
```

I got this error，then I use

```
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@hostname
```

the problem sloved.Maybe you could use hostname.